# The default color for the title of visited questions

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

In most stack exchange websites which I have visited, the color of the title of an already visited question is lighter than a non-visited question. Visually this is helpful. In History.SE the visited questions have a darker color. Can this be changed?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the same with all sites that are "beta". They share the same site template. They are listed [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and all have blue logos.

I don't know how this can be changed, however.